# Filling a plotted line both below and above the line

Tags: plotting, color

I'm relatively new to *Mathematica*. I tried looking for a solution online but couldn't find anything. I want to fill a plotted line both above the line (one color) and below (another color).  For example, the line might be given by `y = 1 - x` over domain (0, 1) and with range (0, 1).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Filling -> { 1 -> Top, 1 -> {Bottom, {Green, Blue}}}
]
```

but I think there may be a neater solution.

Comment: Great- this works perfectly. Thanks to Jonie and Mike!

Answer (score 4):

For an above and below type fill, as an alternative to @Jonie you can use `FillingStyle`:

> `FillingStyle->{Subscript[g, -],Subscript[g, +]}` specifies that the
>   filling should be done with `Subscript[g, -]` when a point, curve or
>   surface lies below the object being filled to, and with `Subscript[g,
>   +]` when it lies above.

```
Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, 
 FillingStyle -> {Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

After re-reading I am not entirely sure what you are looking for. If you want the fill constrained in the x direction as well then:

```
Plot[{If[0 <= x <= 1, 1 - x], 1 - x}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Axis}, FillingStyle -> {Green, Blue}]
```

[image]